# TI Basic Homescreen moving and collison

Tags: calculator, 2d-games, basic

I followed http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/movement
With succes, with the map in the tutorial. But how do I make the walls of that map visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only option is to use Output() to display everything